# Can I write a program to input the password for unlocking screen?

Tags: android

On my android phone, I set a password for the lock-screen.

I want to know if I can write a program to input the unlock screen password? If yes, how should I do?

Thank you!

Comment: Even if you have written an app to unlock the phone,, how will you run that app when your phone is locked ??

Comment: Why do you want to do it? I've seen many odd Android requirements today.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could do this in theory... It just wouldn't be an application. You'd have to modify the Android Open Source code, and create your own ROM, and get into all of that nonsense :D

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't.  It is not possible.